# Matching offsets of floating menu and containers in order to change class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple menu built of list elements, which floats over full-width containers. Because some of these containers are darker than the rest, I would like to be able to define when each of the menu's elements comes over them.

Therefore I've added some classes to the containers that are darker and written a function which obtains their offsets:

```
function getOffsets(){
    var offsets = [],
        colorChangers = $(".colorChange").length,
        top,
        bottom;

    for(i = 0; i < colorChangers; i++){
        top = $(".colorChange").eq(i).offset().top; // where container begins
        bottom = top + $(".colorChange").eq(i).css("height"); // where container ends
        offsets.push(top);
        offsets.push(bottom);
    }

    return offsets;
}
```

Next I want to compare the offsets of .colorChange containers and menu's elements during window scroll event. 
In case of a match I want to toggle additional class of that element in menu:

```
function setMenu(toggleAt){
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        newPos = 90 + winScrollTop,
        topPos,
        item = $("#FloatMenu ul li"),
        menuItems = item.length;

    if(winScrollTop > 90){
        $("#FloatMenu").is(":visible") ? "" : $("#FloatMenu").show();
        topPos = (newPos - 90) + 10;        
        $("#FloatMenu").css("top", topPos);
    } else{
        $("#FloatMenu").hide();
    }

    for(i = 0; i < menuItems; i++){
        $this = item.eq(i);
        for(var j in toggleAt){
            $this.offset().top == toggleAt[j] ? $this.toggleClass("white") : ""; // toggle class "white"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work properly (from time to time if you use the scrollbar slowly), any idea why? Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37Wv4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i see the solution :

-On scroll
--Get menu element offset top;
--Get container that starts at that point (offset) with document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
--Check if element has class .colorChange , if not search element.parents('colorChange') to see if any of it's parents has the colorChange class.
-- If it has that class , change the element's color .

Now ill try some coding (hope it helps a bit):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    $('.menu_elment').each(function(index) {
        menu_elem_offset_top = $(this).offset().top;  
        container_elem = document.elementFromPoint(0,$(this).offset().top);
        if($(container_elem).hasClass('colorChange') || $(container_elem).parents('.colorChange').length != 0) {
            // change the color of the menu 
            $(this).css({'color':'#fff'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: document.elementFromPoint method returns the closest element which doesn't necessarily mean it has the same top offset as each of the menu items. Therefore they turn white way to early. Thanks for an answer though

Comment: elementFromPoint returns the element at a given point in document ... the topmost element . It's your job to find the container colorChange relative to the elementFromPoint , with parents() method or any other helpfull method ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint